# Crittercism SDK version 2.3.5 for iOs

Tags: ios, crittercism

I'm using crittercism to get the crash report from my iPad app. I want to know if the app crashed last time when it was loaded, but it seems that the CrittercismDelegate which contains
function crittercismDidCrashOnLastLoad is not working.

Any advice? Has someone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

Look like this was fixed in v3.2.6 of the library:

https://www.crittercism.com/developers/downloads

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug where the delegate wasn't getting called until the load after a crash was sent to our server instead of after a crash was detected in the app.  We pushed out a fix for this bug in v3.2.6.  Make sure you are using the following to set the delegate:

[[Crittercism sharedInstance] setDelegate: whateverObjectYouWant]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed using v_3_2_6 sdk the bug for setting the delegate is resolved.